# Request to change "please delete me" to something less... sad

Tags: discussion, status-completed, user-accounts

User [please delete me](https://pets.stackexchange.com/users/34/please-delete-me) (aka p.t.) was a prominent user in the early time of the Beta and still has a high value, but was not deleted from the system (probably due to the utility the user provided to community in the form of questions and answers) or genericized.

User "Chad" was, at some point, removed seemingly entirely from the system (questions, comments, answers and all?).  Was "Chad" replaced with a generic "user###" or deleted entirely?

Considering user prevalence, I think the name "please delete me" provides a somewhat distressing tone to any answer provided, and it would be best to either transform the user into a generic "user###" if possible, or rename to something innocuous like "NoLongerAUser".

Is this possible?

Preservation of questions / answers from "please delete me" would be preferred over other options.

Comment: Yes, but I haven't removed because of the reputation hit.

Comment: Can't the user be renamed or made "generic" and information preserved?

Comment: If not, I'm thinking we have project "replicate user 'please delete me'" ahead of us.

Comment: OK; now that I know who it is, the user is active on other SE sites, but not this account.  I would think there would be a way to "de-link" a user's account from a specific SE site.

Comment: Not by a moderator though.

Comment: @JohnCavan As I recall when the user formally know as Chad left there was a change in my rep, and in several others.  So not sure there would be a big rep hit now.  In any case can we just convert all of the Q&A for the user to community?

Comment: @JamesJenkins - that requires the SE folks to do it. If we delete, then the rep hit will happen.

Comment: We don't want to delete there is some value in the posts and we want to keep them.  Is the comment from JoshDM going to get Robert's attention or do we need to do something else to get SE involved?

Comment: @JamesJenkins - Robert should see it, but he probably gets a lot of comments and mentions to wade through and it is the weekend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While John posts (in the edit) that **"Robert has completed the deletion without the rep impact."**, I still got hit with a massive -8 reputation penalty.  :-)

Glad to see the questions, answers, and participation are intact.  Thanks.

Comment: No rep hit for me, so I wonder if it was another user. I would have assumed that PT had voted on a few of my questions/answers over time, though maybe not.